# Azure Functions broken out of the box: System.Net.Http conflict

Tags: azure, azure-functions, system.net.httpwebrequest

This is similar to recently reported problems, but I could not find an actual fix.  I cannot get Azure functions to compile out of the box for the most basic example.  Here's my repro:

1. Create an Azure Functions project in Visual studio 2017 (15.4.0, and also 15.5 prerel)
2. Right-click on the project and select "add item"
3. Add an azure function, Http Trigger, default options.

Result:  When I try to compile, I get the following error:

`Error    CS0433  The type 'HttpResponseMessage' exists in both 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'`

I've tried to install 4.3.0 by hand, and that doesn't help.  I can't install anything earlier than 4.3 because I get an error that the package restore failed.

Any ideas for a workaround?

EDIT: I had a friend create the same project on his machine an it worked.  When I copy the project to my machine, it fails.   My machine is a recently installed Windows 10 pre-release.  That's the only thing I can think of that seems like a significant difference.

Comment: What do you get when you run `gacutil -l System.Net.Http`? On released Win10, I get `System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0`. Maybe they changed something?

Comment: Another test: capture and share the output from running `msbuild YourProjectName.csproj /binaryLogger`

Comment: Gacutil output:
System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL

Comment: Output of msbuild:  https://pastebin.com/uw3rEhAK

Comment: Still can't get this to compile.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check if there are NuGet package updates available? Also, if you open my test app https://github.com/davidebbo-test/FunctionAppHttpBenchmark, are you able to build it?

Comment: For NuGet, specifically make sure you reference Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions version 1.0.6.

Answer (score 0):

There was [an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/pull/1663) with one of the versions of the .NET Core SDK that shipped in one of the 15.5 Previews that caused this problem:

- Open a command prompt and type "dotnet --version"
- If it indicates that it's using "15.5.0-preview-xxxx"
- Open "Add Remove Programs"
- Uninstall the "Microsoft .NET Core SDK - 15.5.0"